# Return records based on occurences number

Tags: mysql

I have the following records in a db table 'fb_list' and I would like to query it in order to retrieve all the records where the count of 'Assoc' is less than 4 by Rank order.

```
Rank    Name    Assoc
1   PLAYER1 CHN
2   PLAYER2 CHN
3   PLAYER3 CHN
4   PLAYER4 CHN
5   PLAYER5 JPN
6   PLAYER6 BRA
7   PLAYER7 TPE
8   PLAYER8 CHN
9   PLAYER9 SWE
10  PLAYER10 GER
```

The expected result should return records 1-3,5-7,9,10
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+, with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.`rank`, t.name, t.assoc
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by assoc order by `rank`) rn
  from fb_list
) t
where t.rn < 4
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vw1KmNW8HxopCeSmiBmmb1/0).

For previous versions

```
select t.`rank`, t.name, t.assoc
from fb_list t
where (select count(*) from  fb_list where assoc = t.assoc and `rank` < t.rank) < 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vw1KmNW8HxopCeSmiBmmb1/2).

Results:

```
| rank | name     | assoc |
| ---- | -------- | ----- |
| 1    | PLAYER1  | CHN   |
| 2    | PLAYER2  | CHN   |
| 3    | PLAYER3  | CHN   |
| 5    | PLAYER5  | JPN   |
| 6    | PLAYER6  | BRA   |
| 7    | PLAYER7  | TPE   |
| 9    | PLAYER9  | SWE   |
| 10   | PLAYER10 | GER   |
```

Comment: this works for MySQL 8.0+ but is there something for earlier versions? Thanks.

Comment: See my 2nd query.